# WPF 2 columns layout container

Tags: c#, wpf, wrappanel, uniformgrid

How can I create layout container that I can use as the `ItemsPanel` of an `ItemsControl`
that stacks the items in two columns and uses the right column for the remaining items that didn't have enough space in the left column (something like a uniform grid mixed with wrap panel).

For example:

four items with the pretty much same height will show as the following:

[image]

four items where two has significally smaller width will show like this:

[image]

Comment: What if the remaining items don't fit into the right column? If you make sure that this never happens, you could well use a vertical WrapPanel.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try WrapPanel with Vertical Orientation

```
<WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical" Height="200">
    <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="2" Height="100" Width="100"/>
    <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="2" Height="100"  Width="100"/>
    <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="2" Height="100"  Width="100"/>
    <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="2" Height="100"  Width="100"/>
</WrapPanel>
```

> output
>   [image]

```
<WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical" Height="200">
    <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="2" Height="100" Width="100" />
    <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="2" Height="50"  Width="100" />
    <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="2" Height="50"  Width="100" />
    <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="2" Height="200"  Width="100" />
</WrapPanel>
```

> Output

[image]

**Edit:** As your comment says wrappanel doesnt fit your requirement .Lets create our panel according to your requrement.

Below is a Custom Panel that sets the controls Vertically and when the Height of children goes more than Panel Height it moves the children to next column exactly same as WrapPanel with Vertical orientation but It has a property Columns which user can specify in xaml and the Panel wont create more than that Columns value

> CustomPanel.cs

```
    public class CustomPanel : Panel
{
    //TODO :Create as Attached Property
    public int Columns { get; set; }

    // Default public constructor 
    public CustomPanel(): base()
    {
    }

    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
    {
        Size size = ArrangeAndMeasure(availableSize, true);
        if (double.IsInfinity(availableSize.Height) || double.IsInfinity(availableSize.Width))
            return size;
        else
            return availableSize;
    }

    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
    {
        return ArrangeAndMeasure(finalSize, false);
    }

    Size ArrangeAndMeasure(Size finalSize,bool isMeasure)
    {
        //if columns not specified set it value 1.
        Columns = Columns == 0 ? 1 : Columns;
        Size size = new Size(0, 0);
        double maxWidth = 0.0;
        int colCount = 1;

        foreach (UIElement child in InternalChildren)
        {
            if ((size.Height + child.DesiredSize.Height > finalSize.Height) && Columns >= colCount)
            {
                //if all height consumed move to next column
                size.Width += maxWidth;
                size.Height = 0.0;
                colCount++;
            }

            if (isMeasure)
                child.Measure(finalSize);
            else
                child.Arrange(new Rect(new Point(size.Width, size.Height), child.DesiredSize));

            size.Height += child.DesiredSize.Height;

            if (maxWidth < child.DesiredSize.Width)
                maxWidth = child.DesiredSize.Width;
        }
        return size; 
    }
}
```

> xaml

```
 <local:CustomPanel Height="200" Columns="2">
    <Border BorderBrush="LimeGreen" BorderThickness="2" Height="200" Width="100"  />
    <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="2" Height="50"  Width="100"  />
    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" Height="50"  Width="100"  />
    <Border BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="2" Height="50"  Width="100"  />
    <Border BorderBrush="Yellow" BorderThickness="2" Height="50"  Width="100"  />
</local:CustomPanel>
```

> output

[image]

> xaml

```
 <local:CustomPanel Height="200" Columns="2">
    <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="2" Height="50"  Width="100"  />
    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" Height="50"  Width="100"  />
    <Border BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="2" Height="50"  Width="100"  />
    <Border BorderBrush="Yellow" BorderThickness="2" Height="50"  Width="100"  />
</local:CustomPanel>
```

> Output

[image]

> xaml

```
<local:CustomPanel Height="200" Columns="2">
    <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="2" Height="50"  Width="100"  />
    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" Height="50"  Width="100"  />
    <Border BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="2" Height="50"  Width="100"  />
    <Border BorderBrush="Yellow" BorderThickness="2" Height="200"  Width="100"  />
</local:CustomPanel>
```

> Output
>   [image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem with this is that when window is resized to a bigger width the wrapPanel expands them to more than two columns and I don't want that ...

Comment: See Edit part.I hope this will help.

Comment: +1 for the detailed answer. Thank you very much for that! I went in the custom layout direction but created my own panel cause your solution didn't quite work for me. Unfortunately, due to company policy I cannot share my code here, so I'll accept your answer. Thanks again!